# DBContext EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Trabajo con EFCore 3.1 necesito que mi DbContext lea la key que tengo en el archivo appsettings.json, mi código es el siguiente.

Json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"CatalogoInquilino": "Server=.;Database=CatalogoInquilino;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

Startup

```
services.AddDbContext<CatalogoInquilinoContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CatalogoInquilino"));
        });

        services.AddTransient<ISdServidor, SdServidor>();
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
```

Capa de datos

```
public class CatalogoInquilinoContext : DbContext
{
    public CatalogoInquilinoContext()
    {

    }
    public CatalogoInquilinoContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    //    => options.UseSqlServer(@"CatalogoInquilino");

    public virtual DbSet<Inquilino> Inquilinos { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BaseDato> BaseDatos { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Servidor> Servidores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new InquilinoMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BaseDatoMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ServidorMap());
    }
}
```

No logro conectarme a la base de datos

Métodos

```
public async Task Create(T entity)
    {
        using (var context = new CatalogoInquilinoContext())
        {
            context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:
Para leer la cadena de conexión hay que instalar 3 dependencias desde Nuget

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Luego, puede usar el siguiente código para leer la cadena de conexión, donde sea que los necesite

ConfigureServices

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyKey");
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
```

DbContext

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private string connectionString;
    public MyContext() : base()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
        var configuration = builder.Build();
        connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyKey").ToString();
    }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
```

lml